# Optimizing existing tables by changing data types

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Lets say i have a table with 10,000 rows and one of the columns is of type INT and unsigned. If i alter the column to be of type SMALLINT and unsigned will it shrink the space the existing data takes on the disk? or only future inserts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104093/. I'd be more concerned about the potential truncation of your data...

Comment: This is more appropriate for [dba.se]

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for the link, helpful!

Comment: @JimGarrison They idea of having niche Q&A is great, the only problem must of them have a fraction of active compared to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it and see?  It's easy enough to get your own empirical data.

How much space do you imagine you'll save?  You change one 4-byte INT into a 2-byte SMALLINT, you'll save two bytes, or 20K for the entire table.  Are you *that* hard up for disk space?

Comment: Thanks for your input Andy. I'm more concern on the size of the index, the smallest the index footprint the better query performance. 10,000 rows is actually a fraction of all the data, im talking about Gig tables

Comment: You say "the smallest the index footprint the better query performance" which is theoretically true, but without measuring, you don't know, and could be wasting your time.